# Rails find all records for a collection of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :post
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations
end
```

For the association above I need to do following query.

```
@posts = Post.includes(:categories).where(active: true)
@categories = @posts.categories
```

Obviously this query `@categories = @posts.categories` does not work but how would I do this?

**Update**:
With both answers below I get this error

```
Category Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."post" IN (SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts")
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: categories.post: SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."post" IN (SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: categories.post: SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."post" IN (SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts")
```

Comment: you can not do this, because if you want to have @categories, your line of code need begining by `Category.someting`. Now that you have correction relation, you can do `@categories = Category.joins(:posts).where(posts: { active: true })`

Answer (score 1):

To your `Category` class, add:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, through: :categorizations
```

Then you can do something like:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:categories).where(active: true)
@categories = Category.where(post: @posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one query:

```
@categories = Category.joins(:posts).where(posts: { active: true })
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that error with this code? I can't see the join. Maybe you don't have the association part into the Category model?

Comment: Added all associations

Comment: Please, could you paste the error message of this particular query?

Answer (score 0):

First you need declare relations:

In your `Categorization` model you need to have

```
belongs_to :post
```

And in your `Category`  model

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :posts, through: :categorizations
```

If you forget this, active record suppose that `post` is a column of Category because you never tell him that is a relation